# How to concatenate attributes in RSpec 3.12 requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Edit views in my application provide expected data fields, and also extra fields that do not belong to the model, such as annotations and translations, which are processed by the controller method before saving the edited record.

When writing requests tests, I need to provide these extra fields to the Post method, in addition to the model fields:

```
RSpec.describe "Playgrounds", type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers 
  # Playground. As you add validations to Playground, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.

  let(:user) { create(:user, is_admin: true) }
  let(:playground) {FactoryBot.create(:playground)}

  # User login 
  before do
    login_as user, scope: :user
  end

  describe "POST /playgrounds" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      # Use per context let instead 
      let(:attributes) { attributes_for(:playground) }
      it "creates a playground" do
        expect {
          post '/entities', params: {
            playground: attributes, 
            playground_name_fr: "Donnée de test", 
            playground_name_de: "", 
            playground_name_en: "Test data", 
            playground_name_it: "Dati del test", 
            playground_description_fr: "Ceci n'est qu'un test", 
            playground_description_de: "", 
            playground_description_en: "This is just a test", 
            playground_description_it: "Questo è solo un test"
          }
        }.to change(Playground, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to have_http_status 302
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

In order to define these 8 fields used for translation only once, I would like to define a Hash variable, and add it to the playground Hash:

```
RSpec.describe "Playgrounds", type: :request do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers 
  # Playground. As you add validations to Playground, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.

  let(:user) { create(:user, is_admin: true) }
  let(:playground) {FactoryBot.create(:playground)}
  let(:fields) do 
    { 
      playground_name_fr: "Donnée de test", 
      playground_name_de: "", 
      playground_name_en: "Test data", 
      playground_name_it: "Dati del test", 
      playground_description_fr: "Ceci n'est qu'un test", 
      playground_description_de: "", 
      playground_description_en: "This is just a test", 
      playground_description_it: "Questo è solo un test" 
    }
  end

    # User login 
    before do
        login_as user, scope: :user
    end

  describe "POST /playgrounds" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      # Use per context let instead 
      let(:attributes) { attributes_for(:playground) }
      it "creates a playground" do
        expect {
          post '/entities', params: {
            playground: attributes < fields 
          }
        }.to change(Playground, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to have_http_status 302
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

But then I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error:
   params.require(:playground)
         .permit(:code,
                 :status_id,
                 :logo,
                 :organisation_id,
                 :responsible_id,
                 :deputy_id,
                 :sort_code,
                 name: {},
                 description: {}

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `permit' for "false":String
```

As the first syntax works as expected, and the second does not, I probably inserted the fields at the wrong place or level, but I can't find out how to solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably want `post '/entities', params: { playground: attributes.merge(fields) }` instead of `attributes < fields`.

Comment: You are right, I am mixing up with Arrays ... This is a good step, but not the solution yet, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was to reproduce the **params** hash expected by the controller under test. Beside some tokens, **params** contains:

- The playground hash - corresponding to permitted parameters as listed in the controller
- Other parameters - corresponding to the extrafields of the edited form

Example:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"uJysIqrglzyBSAx9O49TRZ4NfggMw9C59/w==",
"playground"=><ActionController::Parameters {
    "code"=>"TESTB", 
    "sort_code"=>"", 
    "organisation_id"=>"0", 
    "responsible_id"=>"1",  
    "deputy_id"=>"2"} permitted: false>, 
"playground_name_fr"=>"Société test", 
"playground_name_de"=>"Data governance", 
"playground_name_en"=>"TESTBC", 
"playground_name_it"=>"Società di test", 
"playground_description_fr"=>"", 
"playground_description_de"=>"", 
"playground_description_en"=>"", 
"playground_description_it"=>"", 
"controller"=>"playgrounds", 
"action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Then the solution is to add **fields** hash to the **params** hash itself:

```
    expect {
      post '/entities', params: {
        playground: attributes
      }.merge(fields)
    }.to change(Playground, :count).by(1)
```

Thanks a lot Max and Eugen for putting me on the way!

Answer (score 2):

To merge hashes together you use [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
expect {
  post '/entities', params: {
    playground: attributes.merge(fields)
  }
}.to change(Playground, :count).by(1)
```

Ruby doesn't have an operator shorthand for this. [`Hash#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-3C) is actually used to test if a hash is a subset of another hash and returns a boolean.